# Error when trying to install node.JS with putty?

Tags: node.js, git, cordova, putty, ionic-framework

How do I fix this when setting up `node.JS` with `putty`? I tried setting up the `%PATH%` but when i've done everything and the use `echo %PATH%` nothing comes up?

> **npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/cordova**
>
> **npm** http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/cordova
>
> **npm ERR!** Error: EACCES, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'
>
> **npm ERR!**  { [Error: EACCES, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules']
>
> **npm ERR!**   errno: 3,
>
> **npm ERR!**   code: 'EACCES',
>
> **npm ERR!**   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules',
>
> **npm ERR!**   fstream_type: 'Directory',
>
> **npm ERR!**   fstream_path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova',
>
> **npm ERR!**   fstream_class: 'DirWriter',
>
> **npm ERR!**   fstream_stack:
>
> **npm ERR!**    [ '/usr/lib/nodejs/fstream/lib/writer.js:171:23',
>
> **npm ERR!**      '/usr/lib/nodejs/mkdirp/index.js:37:53',
>
> **npm ERR!**     'Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)' ] }
>
> **npm ERR!** Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.
>
> **npm ERR!** System Linux 3.16.0-29-generic
>
> **npm ERR!** command "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "cordova"
>
> **npm ERR!** cwd /home/azureuser
>
> **npm ERR!** node -v v0.10.25
>
> **npm ERR!** npm -v 1.3.10
>
> **npm ERR!** path /usr/local/lib/node_modules
>
> **npm ERR!** fstream_path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova
>
> **npm ERR!** fstream_type Directory
>
> **npm ERR!** fstream_class DirWriter
>
> **npm ERR!** code EACCES
>
> **npm ERR!** errno 3
>
> **npm ERR!** stack Error: EACCES, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'
>
> **npm ERR!** fstream_stack /usr/lib/nodejs/fstream/lib/writer.js:171:23
>
> **npm ERR!** fstream_stack /usr/lib/nodejs/mkdirp/index.js:37:53
>
> **npm ERR!** fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
>
> **npm ERR!** Additional logging details can be found in:
>
> **npm ERR!**     /home/azureuser/npm-debug.log
>
> **npm ERR!** not ok code 0

Comment: `npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need administrator privileges to install global npm packages. Try running your command as root. For example:

```
sudo npm install -g cordova
```